# What factors contribute to the fact that only a handful of countries manufacture aircraft jet engines?

Tags: technology, aircraft

The USA (GE, Pratt & Whitney), Russia (NPO Saturn, Klimov), France (Snecma) and the UK (Rolls Royce) are the only countries that have aircraft jet engine manufacturers. What factors might contribute to the reasons that there are no German, Canadian, Israeli, Spanish or Italian companies doing this?

I heard the allied countries of WW2 captured German engineers and developed their industries.

Is there any documentation in the final treaties to indicate that this might be connected to WW2 somehow?

Comment: It is not necessarily the question of being **able** to, but also of willing to invest the money to **bother** doing so when buying from those listed is cheaper.

Comment: Agree with @DVK.  And in the case of Germany, it should probably be 'no longer bother', as they had the first working [jet fighter aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_262)

Comment: [List of aircraft engine manufacturers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_engine_manufacturers) - The list isn't as limited as you seem to think. A prominent example is [Kawasaki Heavy Industries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawasaki_Heavy_Industries_Aerospace_Company) (since you seem to imply that the losing side of WW2 somehow stopped producing jet engines).

Comment: The way this was phrased seemed a bit leading (and Nationalistic), which is perhaps why it garnered a couple of close requests. Hopefully this formuation is more answerable and less trollish.

Comment: @YannisRizos You might want to consider converting your comment to an answer. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @YannisRizos and partially Luke, the list of aircraft engine manufacturers is not the same thing as the list of aircraft _jet_ engine manufacturers. Jet engines are much harder to produce and are also more costly to produce, and so it would be inaccurate to use the list you mentioned.

Comment: @reliableSource Hm? You are kinda pointing the obvious there... Did you actually check the list? If not, do, there are certainly more _jet_ engine manufacturers than the question suggests.

Comment: @YannisRizos I did check the link, but I don't really want to get this comment closed for eliciting debate. I realize that there are more, but just think that your list would not be the most appropriate one.

Answer (score 9):

The premise of your question is false. Here's a brief (and incomplete) list of current jet engine manufacturers:

- **[MTU Aero Engines](http://mtu.de/en/index.html) (Germany)**

  Jet engines are their main product, usually in conjuction with other manufacturers and/or manufacturing consortiums. They hold 33% of the development share and 30% of the production share of [EUROJET Turbo GmbH](http://www.eurojet.de/en/), 40% of [Turbo Union](http://www.turbounion.co.uk/) and 25.25% of [International Aero Engines AG](http://i-a-e.com/).
- **[Avio Group](http://www.aviogroup.com/en/) (Italy)**

  They manufacture a series of [civil](http://www.aviogroup.com/en/catalog/civil/engines) and [military engines](http://www.aviogroup.com/en/catalog/military/engines), and hold 21% of the development share and 19.5% of the production share of EUROJET Turbo GmbH. They also hold 20% of Turbo Union
- **[Industria de Turbo Propulsores](http://www.itp.es/web/Sec_home/wf_home.aspx) (Spain)**

  [Sener Aeroespacial](http://www.sener-aerospace.com/AEROESPACIAL/home/en) (Spain) owns the majority (53.125%) of ITP, the rest (46.875%) is owned by [Rolls-Royce](http://www.rolls-royce.com/) (UK). ITP holds 13% of the development share and 16% of the production share of EUROJET Turbo GmbH.
- **[Kawasaki Aerospace Company](http://www.khi.co.jp/english/aero/) (Japan)**

  A couple of examples of their recent work are the [XP-1](http://www.khi.co.jp/english/aero/product/airplanes/xp_1.html), the [C-1](http://www.khi.co.jp/english/aero/product/airplanes/c_1.html) and the [C-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawasaki_C-2) military aircrafts. They are part of the [Japanese Aero Engine Corporation consortium](http://www.jaec.or.jp/) through their parent company, Kawasaki Heavy Industries, and thus also part of International Aero Engines.
- **[IHI Corporation](http://www.ihi.co.jp/en/) (Japan)**

  They've designed and developed a variety of jet engines, a recent example of an engine solely developed by IHI is the [F7 turbofan engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IHI_Corporation_F7). They are also part of the Japanese Aero Engine Corporation consortium (and thus part of International Aero Engines).
- **[Mitsubishi Heavy Industries](http://www.mhi.co.jp/en/) (Japan)**

  They seem to be doing *everything* related to aerospace. Couldn't find specific mentions of *recent* jet engines they've build, but since they build Japan's main rockets (the [H-IIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-IIA) and [H-IIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-IIB)), I guess they deserve a honourable mention. They are also part of the Japanese Aero Engine Corporation consortium (and thus part of International Aero Engines).
- **[Ivchenko-Progress ZMKB](http://www.ivchenko-progress.com) (Ukraine)**

  They manufacture [a variety of turbofan, turboshaft, turboprop, and propfan engines](http://www.ivchenko-progress.com/welcome.do?id=6).
- **[TAI](https://www.tai.com.tr/en) (Turkey)**

  They build [GE F110 engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_F110) under license from General Electric, and they've also build at least one jet engine powered UAVs, the [ŞİMŞEK](https://www.tai.com.tr/en/project/simsek). A (perhaps) weak example.
- **[Hellenic Aerospace Industry](http://www.haicorp.com/) (Greece)**

  The E1-79 ΠΗΓΑΣΟΣ (Pegasus) UAV is jet powered and was solely designed and developed by HAI. The project is now part of the [Dassault nEUROn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_nEUROn). Another (perhaps) weak example, but couldn't resist my Greek pride ;P

I have no idea why jet engine manufacturing (or lack of) would be connected to WW2, at least in the way you seem to imply. In any case, several companies that are based in the losing side of WW2 are key players in aerospace and if they build rockets, satellites and space station components, who cares if they are building jet engines or not.